# Multiple modules with different Python versions in a single project

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, flask, pip, module

I want to use Flask Restplus api from python 2.7.18 and selenium-wire from python 3.11 as well in same project, I don't know how can I install different version dependencies in a single project. Need Help.

## from python==2.7.18

Flask RESTplus
Flask

## from python==3.11

selenium
selenium-wire

Comment: Could you explain why?